# The this keyword in classes

Tags: java, class, oop, this

I am learning Java, and going through the documentation.

There is a line on [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) which I am not able to understand -

> ...
>   Also, class methods cannot use the this keyword as there is no instance for this to refer to.
>   ...

I thought that it was only static class methods which could not use the `this` keyword.

To test this, I wrote the following, which compiles.

```
import java.math.*;

class Point {

    public int x, y;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public double getDistanceFromOrigin() {
        return Math.sqrt(this.x*this.x + this.y*this.y);
    }

}
```

I have a class all right, in which a method refers to `this`.

Am I misinterpreting things in some way?

Comment: *I thought that it was only `static` class methods which could not use the `this` keyword.* and you're right.

Comment: Your methods aren't static, so they can access `this`.

Comment: class method -> classs level method -> static methods-> you can use it without instancing, so they are static, so you can't use this keyboard cause you have an object from this class.

Comment: I believe you've misunderstood that "class methods" are actually static methods, as they apply to the class rather than an instance of it.

Comment: please fix your link (remove the comma after .html)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Class methods *are* static methods. A "class method" is a method that is bound to the class definition (using the `static` keyword), as opposed to object/instance methods, which you write so that you can call them on objects you build based on that class.

The code you've written has two object/instance methods, and no class methods. If you want a class method in Java, you make it static, and then you cannot use `this`.

Answer (score 1):

> I thought that it was only `static` class methods which could not use the `this` keyword.

You're right. The `static` methods in a class belong to the class, not to the object reference. So to prove your sentence, just add a `static` method and use `this` keyword in it. For example:

```
class Point {

    public int x, y;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public double getDistanceFromOrigin() {
        return Math.sqrt(this.x*this.x + this.y*this.y);
    }

    public static double getDistanceBetweenPoints(Point point1, Point point2) {
        //uncomment and it won't compile
        //double result = this.x;
        //fancy implementation...
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, only `static` class methods cannot use the `this` keyword, but your code example is non-static so `this` is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `this` inside an instance method which will refer to the current instance.

```
public double getDistanceFromOrigin() {
    return Math.sqrt(this.x*this.x + this.y*this.y);
}
```

If you change the method to a static method , `this` will not be available , because static methods are tied to the class and not to a particular instance of the class whereas `this` refers to the current instance of a class if used inside a method.

```
public static double getDistanceFromOrigin() {
    return Math.sqrt(this.x*this.x + this.y*this.y); // compilation error here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After reading the content at the link you've posted, It seems to use the verbiage `Class methods` to refer to **static** methods

---

> **Class Methods**
>
> The Java programming language supports static methods as well as
>   static variables. Static methods, which have the static modifier in
>   their declarations, should be invoked with the class name, without the
>   need for creating an instance of the class, as in

You can't use `this` in static methods because there is no instance(no `this`) to reference.